# Modify JavaScript to access variable

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with some code which enlarges text based on the size of the div it's in. It can be seen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZqXXd

```
$(function() {

  var outer = $('div'), inner = $('h1'),
  difference = outer.width()-inner.width(),
  ratio = outer.width()/inner.width(),
  style = 'translateX(' + difference/2 + 'px) ' + 'scale(' + ratio + ')';
  inner.css({'webkit-transform': style, transform: style});
});
```

However, I'm trying to modify it to use a variable with sizes in, not get it from the div. This was my attempt that doesn't seem to work:

```
$(function() {

  var width = "400",
  var inner = $('h1'),
  difference = width -inner.width(),
  ratio = width /inner.width(),
  style = 'translateX(' + difference/2 + 'px) ' + 'scale(' + ratio + ')';
  inner.css({'webkit-transform': style, transform: style});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the comma (`','`) after `var width = "400"` with a semicolon. Your current code throws a syntax error.

The corrected code would be:

```
$(function() {

  var width = "400"; // <-----
  var inner = $('h1'),
  difference = width -inner.width(),
  ratio = width /inner.width(),
  style = 'translateX(' + difference/2 + 'px) ' + 'scale(' + ratio + ')';
  inner.css({'webkit-transform': style, transform: style});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. May I just ask why that is, since the other var has a comma and is ok?

Comment: @Jimmy The reason is that the lines after the second var statement all belong to the preceding `var`. This is the same as e.g. `var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;`, just broken up into multiple lines. It is always a good idea to indent variable declarations, this makes the code much easier to read and to understand.